# Problem converting list to nested dictionary in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I'm fairly new to Python and am working with nested dictionaries.
I'm receiving a list of dictionaries from a webpage below is an example:

```
    Recipes = [{'Ingredient': 'Pork Mince', 'Quantity': 1, 'Recipe': 'Chilli Tofu'},
     {'Ingredient': 'Courgettes', 'Quantity': 2, 'Recipe': 'Chilli Tofu'},
     {'Ingredient': 'Firm Tofu', 'Quantity': 1, 'Recipe': 'Chilli Tofu'},
     {'Ingredient': 'Garlic', 'Quantity': 1, 'Recipe': 'Chilli Tofu'},
     {'Ingredient': 'Chilli Bean Paste', 'Quantity': 1, 'Recipe': 'Chilli Tofu'},
     {'Ingredient': 'Chillies', 'Quantity': 1, 'Recipe': 'Chilli Tofu'},
     {'Ingredient': 'Spring Onions', 'Quantity': 2, 'Recipe': 'Chilli Tofu'},
     {'Ingredient': 'Courgettes', 'Quantity': 2, 'Recipe': 'Prawn & Courgettes'},
     {'Ingredient': 'Prawns', 'Quantity': 1, 'Recipe': 'Prawn & Courgettes'},
     {'Ingredient': 'Onions', 'Quantity': 1, 'Recipe': 'Prawn & Courgettes'},
     {'Ingredient': 'Garlic', 'Quantity': 1, 'Recipe': 'Prawn & Courgettes'},
     {'Ingredient': 'Chillies', 'Quantity': 1, 'Recipe': 'Prawn & Courgettes'}]
```

I'd like to format this into a nested dictionary so that I end up with the 'Recipe' value of the dictionaries as a key and the ingredients and quantities as part of a sub dictionary. So it would look something like this this...

```
{'Chilli Tofu': {
     'Spring Onions': 2,
     'Pork Mince': 1,
     'Firm Tofu': 1,
     'Courgettes': 2,
     'Garlic': 1,
     'Chilli Bean Paste': 1,
     'Chillies':1,
     'Spring Onions': 2
}, 
'Prawn & Courgettes': {
     'Chillies': 1,
     'Courgettes': 2,
      etc...
}}
```

I'm able to get part way there with this code:

```
format_recipes = {}
for r in recipes:
    format_recipes[r['Recipe']] = {r['Ingredient']: r['Quantity']}
```

However when I run the above I only ever get a dictionary that consists of the following:

`{'Chilli Tofu': {'Spring Onions': 2}, 'Prawn & Courgettes': {'Chillies': 1}}`

It seems my nested dictionary is continually getting overwritten in the loop and I only ever get the last ingredient and quantity in the list for that recipe.

I'm not sure how to prevent this from happening and append to the list of key:value pairs instead of overwriting them. Any ideas?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are overwriting the dictionary value each time you do:

```
format_recipes[r['Recipe']] = {r['Ingredient']: r['Quantity']}
```

You can instead use `update` together with `setdefault` which will set the initial nested dict:

```
format_recipes = {}
for item in Recipes:
    format_recipes.setdefault(item['Recipe'], {}).update({item['Ingredient']: item['Quantity']})
```

format_recipes will then be:

```
{'Chilli Tofu': {'Pork Mince': 1,
  'Courgettes': 2,
  'Firm Tofu': 1,
  'Garlic': 1,
  'Chilli Bean Paste': 1,
  'Chillies': 1,
  'Spring Onions': 2},
 'Prawn & Courgettes': {'Courgettes': 2,
  'Prawns': 1,
  'Onions': 1,
  'Garlic': 1,
  'Chillies': 1}}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are in fact replacing with each iteration the recipe, you need to append it to be a list of dictionaries:

First, you need to define the empty list for each recipe, then append each ingredient

Solution:

```
format_recipes = {}

for r in recipes:
    format_recipes[r['Recipe']] = []

for r in recipes:
    format_recipes[r['Recipe']].append({r['Ingredient']: r['Quantity']})
```

Comment: Many thanks. Marking Mark's answer as accepted as it uses less code.

Comment: you break my heart! haha